# Unity Game Crashes after Unity Loading Splash Screen Finishes

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've tried all sorts of player setting changes and any small tweaks to try and get my Unity game to run, but I consistently get this segfault crash dump right after the load screen about a VSync related method in libunity.so. I have tried changing the VSync Count setting in Quality, but that changes nothing. Thanks ahead of time for any help.

```
I/DEBUG   (  323): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  323): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/d2uc/d2att:4.3/######/###########:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  323): Revision: '16'
I/DEBUG   (  323): pid: 15148, tid: 15148, name: s.SubVer.Covert  >>> es.SubVer.Covert <<<
I/DEBUG   (  323): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  323):     r0 00000001  r1 40109f24  r2 00000001  r3 0000001d
I/DEBUG   (  323):     r4 00000000  r5 64b5bf28  r6 71253503  r7 64b73ec8
I/DEBUG   (  323):     r8 000004a2  r9 4180cc58  sl 71253503  fp 000004a2
I/DEBUG   (  323):     ip 498f60ac  sp beb7afd8  lr 48e53b0c  pc 48e54a44  cpsr 800e0010
I/DEBUG   (  323):     d0  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  d1  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
I/DEBUG   (  323):     d2  000003e800000000  d3  0000000000000014
I/DEBUG   (  323):     d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  323):     d6  431780003f13a403  d7  000000003f800000
I/DEBUG   (  323):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  323):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  323):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  323):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  323):     d16 0000000000000000  d17 000004a271253503
I/DEBUG   (  323):     d18 002e00640069006f  d19 002e006900750067
I/DEBUG   (  323):     d20 0061007200470049  d21 0063006900680070
I/DEBUG   (  323):     d22 0066006600750042  d23 0072005000720065
I/DEBUG   (  323):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000008f0000008f
I/DEBUG   (  323):     d26 0707070703030303  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  323):     d28 0301010101000000  d29 00024e9000024e90
I/DEBUG   (  323):     d30 0001000000010000  d31 0001000000010000
I/DEBUG   (  323):     scr 60000012
I/DEBUG   (  323):
I/DEBUG   (  323): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  323):     #00  pc 004eea44  /data/app-lib/es.SubVer.Covert-1/libunity.so (nativeAddVSyncTime(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long)+24)
I/DEBUG   (  323):     #01  pc 00010b78  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@es.SubVer.Covert-1.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   (  323):
I/DEBUG   (  323): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7af98  64b73ec8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7af9c  000004a2
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afa0  4cc5d550  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afa4  00000024
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afa8  00000016
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afac  00000024
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afb0  4cc5d550  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afb4  4012da0c  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_setspecific+164)
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afb8  4cc5d550  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afbc  00130770
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afc0  71253503  /dev/kgsl-3d0
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afc4  48e53afc  /data/app-lib/es.SubVer.Covert-1/libunity.so     (NativeRuntimeException::GetExceptionState()+96)
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afc8  00000039
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afcc  64b5bf28  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afd0  df0027ad
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afd4  00000000
I/DEBUG   (  323):     #00  beb7afd8  00000039
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afdc  64b5bf28  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afe0  64b74010  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afe4  64b73ec8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afe8  649fd688  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-zygote space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7afec  48458b7c  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@es.SubVer.Covert-1.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   (  323):     #01  beb7aff0  64b58310  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7aff4  00000001
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7aff8  beb7b564  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7affc  64b5bf28  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7b000  00000005
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7b004  64b5bf28  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7b008  64b74010  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7b00c  64b73ec8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7b010  649fd688  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-zygote space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7b014  71253503  /dev/kgsl-3d0
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7b018  000004a2
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7b01c  48461b1b  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@es.SubVer.Covert-1.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7b020  64b73ec8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7b024  64b5bf28  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-alloc space (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7b028  71253503  /dev/kgsl-3d0
I/DEBUG   (  323):          beb7b02c  000004a2
```

Comment: Also, code stripping is disabled.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I figured it out. Turns out, my phone was running out of memory which was causing this segfault. A good lesson for me to remember to compress my textures.